# Import a custom function from the python console

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-custom-function, qgis-python-console

I'm trying to import a custom function from the python console, but it return the error:

```
'QgsExpressionFunction' object is not callable
```

My example function (saved as function.py file in /.qgis2/python/ directory) is:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import qgsfunction
from qgis.core import QgsExpression

@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
def TriangleArea(b,h,feature,parent):
    area = b*h/2.0
    return area
    QgsExpression.registerFunction(TriangleArea)
```

To import and execute the function i use:

```
from function import *

A = TriangleArea(3, 5)
print A
```

what's wrong?

Comment: Is your _function.py_ file saved in your `/.qgis2/python/` directory?

Comment: @Joseph, yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @Joseph 's suggestions I created a function that opens a raster grid and passes the values into a numpy array. The procedure I have adopted is:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import qgsfunction
from qgis.core import QgsExpression
import numpy as np

@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
def OpenGrid(GridPath, feature, parent):
    GridName = QgsRasterLayer(GridPath)

    # Create array 'values_GridName'
    provider = GridName.dataProvider()
    extent = provider.extent()
    rows = GridName.height()
    cols = GridName.width()
    xmin = extent.xMinimum()
    ymax = extent.yMaximum()
    xsize = GridName.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
    ysize = GridName.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()
    block = provider.block(1, extent, cols, rows)
    values_GridName = [ [] for i in range(rows) ]
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            block.value(i,j)
            values_GridName[i].append(block.value(i,j))
    #This code line is used to make sure all numbers are float type
    values_GridName = np.array(values_GridName, dtype = float)
    return values_GridName
```

The function was saved in /.qgis2/python/OpenRlayer.py.

I call the function with the following commands:

```
from OpenRlayer import OpenGrid   

grid_path = path/to/grid.asc
values_Grid = OpenGrid.function(grid_path, None, None)
```

This is how I created the array that contains the grid data and now I can do the operations I need

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following where you can import your `TriangleArea()` function and then use the method `function` to run it:

```
from function import TriangleArea

A = TriangleArea.function(3, 5, None, None)
print A
```

The `feature` and `parent` parameters can be left empty.

[image: Result]

---

Another way is to import your file directly and then call your function:

```
import function

A = function.TriangleArea.function(3, 5, None, None)
print A
```

[image: Result]

---

*Note: I **strongly suggest** you call your file something else to avoid confusion with the `function` method :)*

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work.

Comment: @DomenicoFuoco - Did you restart QGIS?

Comment: Yes I did, but I think your solution is wrong because the function has to be called as file_name.function_name(parameters)

Comment: @DomenicoFuoco - Not necessarily because I used `from function import TriangleArea` which means I can call the function directly. You could use `from function import *` and then use `A = function.TriangleArea.function(3, 5, None, None)`.

Comment: Sorry but function is the name of the file that contains the TriangleArea function. When calling the function, the name of the file must be entered to the left of the point and the name of the function to the right.
It's the classic procedure I've always run and it works correctly if I run it from python idle

Comment: @DomenicoFuoco - I have edited the post with some screenshots because I think there's a little misunderstanding. Your filename is called _function_. But there is a method also called `function()` which is used to run `TriangleArea`. I strongly suggest you change your filename to something else to avoid confusion.

Comment: I'm really sorry I knew badly.
I followed your suggestion and the script works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: @DomenicoFuoco - No need to apologise! Glad you got it working :)